# Why can't I login after a hard reset?

Tags: login, shutdown, power-management

Ubuntu boots normal, and I can even login in terminal at any TTY (tt1 ~ tty6), **but not in Graphical mode**.

**This happened after a power-suspend**. As I was trying to resume after the system suspended due to a running low battery, and wasn't getting my Ubuntu back, I made a hard reset (power button). I could not login anymore from that moment on.

Answer (score 1):

Hard resets also commonly leave the `~/.Xauthority` file behind, which will prevent the graphical desktop from starting.

It's safe to delete and will be automatically recreated when you restart.

From a tty: `rm .Xauthority`

Answer (score 0):

I've just suffered from powercut-induced corruption so I'm perhaps a bit biased toward that conclusion but nonetheless. I couldn't get past grub so booted to a LiveUSB and ran `sudo fsck -y /dev/...` for my main partition. A lot of worrying notices later and I was back on my desktop.

Failing that I would check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for some sort of indication about what's going on. If X isn't logging you in properly, there should be *something* in there.